# Ubuntu/Wayland: Turn off screen via FN keys

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, brightness, wayland, backlight

On my old laptop, I was able to turn off the screen by pressing `FN + BRIGHTNESS DOWN` until it reached 0 when I was running Linux Mint. Now, I want to replicate this on Ubuntu 20.04 with Wayland, but I cannot replicate the methods shown in other posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408453/turn-off-display-in-ubuntu-on-wayland) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729977/turning-the-brightness-completely-down).

- `xset dpms force off` doesn't work on Wayland,
- `xrandr` doesn't actually turn off the monitor backlight,
- Setting screen saver `dbus-send` shows no effect and also doesn't turn off the screen,
- `echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` works, but is hard to undo and might not work when switching to the NVidia card - and it requires `root`,
- Locking the screen with `CTRL + L` also turns off the screen immediately, but it often turns itself on just a few minutes later for no obvious reason.

When I use the FN keys that control the brightness, which method is used to set the screen brightness? Wouldn't it be possible to simply modify the key binding in a way that it reduces the brightness to 0 instead of 15 (in my case)? And is it known why the screen turns itself on after a short time after being locked?

Answer (score 0):

You probably could implement a hack using the tool `light`, which is available in the standard Ubuntu software repositories. After installing, see "man light" to see how it works. For example, the command `light -A 5` will increase brightness with 5 units.

`light` allows to set a minimum brightness - in your case you would set that to 0.

You could then bind the appropriate commands to your <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>BrightnessUp/Down</kbd> keys. For that, disable the default assignment first with the commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-up-static "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screen-brightness-down-static "['']"
```

Then assign the commands to these keys using "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts", "Custom Shortcuts".

To revert to the default behaviour, change `set` in the above commands to `reset` and leave out the last argument.

Comment: `light` apparently doesn't work on my device. Does it work with Wayland? I tried `light -s sysfs/backlight/intel_backlight -A 5` and `light -G` remains at 1.00.

Comment: You will of course need a tool that works on your specific system. It is perhaps wise to edit your question and add information about your hardware, specifically the graphics card.